# Combining maths queries MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is is possible to combine the below queries into single, I am basically interested in getting the result given by the last query.

```
#This is wrong SQL only intended as pseudocode  

SELECT sum(amt) u FROM entry WHERE en_type='some_type' AND num='some_num';
SELECT sum(amt) v FROM entry WHERE en_type='some_other_type' AND num='some_num';
SELECT abal x FROM accounts WHERE num='the_same_num_as_above'; 
SELECT y = x + v - u;
```

Comment: u = v in your example...

Comment: I have edited the question. Now it won't imply u=v.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using subqueries you can do:

```
SELECT -(SELECT sum(amt) u FROM entry WHERE en_type='some_type' AND num='some_num')
       + (SELECT sum(amt) v FROM entry WHERE en_type='some_type' AND num='some_num')
       + (SELECT abal x FROM accounts WHERE num='the_same_num_as_above') AS y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION to make a synthetic three row table, then summarize it.

```
SELECT SUM(x) y FROM
(
  SELECT sum(amt) AS x FROM entry WHERE en_type='some_type' AND num='some_num'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT sum(amt) AS x FROM entry WHERE en_type='some_type' AND num='some_num'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT -abal AS x FROM accounts WHERE num='the_same_num_as_above'
) A
```

I am not sure I understand your 'the_same_num' stuff, so you'll need to work that out.

Comment: It just implies that num remains same across. :)